# Loading a symbol of type Graphic from library with Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Inside Flash, I have a symbol with type graphic in my library and I want to add it to stage using Actionscript 3.  Is this possible?

Flash does not let me set any Linkage Properties for Graphic symbols.

How do I draw stuff in Flash and be able to create multiple instances of that stuff at run time without using MovieClip?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : you can't. However, if you think a movieclip is too heavy, you can use a Sprite instead. A Sprite is the same as a movieclip without the timeline stuff. To do so, transform your symbol into a movieclip, and when you assign a class to your symbol, specify flash.display.Sprite as the base class.

Answer (score 0):

just convert it or put it inside a movieclip so you can access it :)

Comment: Because of performance issues, I need to use Graphic.  I have found doing a lot of nested insert movie clips to be very slow and consumes lots of memory....